# Trying to find if a string contains a word from a list, and if so, return that word. Followed a tutorial but it is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I followed [this tutorial](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-match-cell-contains)

This is how I have entered the formula:
[image: cells with formula]

The formula is: `=INDEX(C4:C5;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C4:C5;B4));0))`

This is the result:
[image: result]

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you are trying to use is an **array formula**. Array formulas need to be finalized with [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)+[enter](/questions/tagged/enter) (*aka* CSE), not just [enter](/questions/tagged/enter).

If you do this correctly, Excel will wrap your formula in maths braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do NOT type these in yourself.

You also need to lock the row numbers of the ranges as absolute row references so they don't change as you drag the formula from D4 to D5.

```
=INDEX(C$4:C$5; MATCH(TRUE; ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$4:C$5; B4)); 0))
```

If you are worried that another user (surely not yourself) may break the array formula by editing it and not using CSE to finalize it, try this alternative in D4 and drag down. It does not require CSE.

```
=INDEX(C$4:C$5; AGGREGATE(15; 7; ROW($1:$2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$4:C$5; B4)); 1))
```

Comment: It works when I tried what you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter, non-array and does not require CSE formula option :

Formula in D4, copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(1,-SEARCH(C$4:C$5,B4),C$4:C$5)
```